# How many boxes of each mixture should the company make to maximize profit? Linear Programming Problem

Tags: linear-programming

> A company makes two snack mixtures.
>   A box of mixture A contains 6 ounces of peanuts, 1 ounce of M&M's, and 4 ounces of raisins and sells for \$4.25.
>   A box of mixture B contains 12 ounces of peanuts, 3 ounces of M&M's, and 2 ounces of raisins and sells for \$6.55.
>   The company has available 5400 ounces of peanuts, 1200 ounces of M&M's, and 2400 ounces of raisins.
>   How many boxes of each mixture should the company make to maximize profit?

I'm suppose to solve using a graph, and I've been watching youtube videos for now over 3 hours and I'm feeling very stuck. I started off wrong because I was trying to do a equation for 2 variables because I thought box A and box B would be 2 variables but now I'm thinking the food would actually make it 3 variables meaning I just did all that work for nothing. I would really appreciate some further assistance on how you guys found the answer. My answer was $x=500$, $y=200$, $z(op)=3685$ .... please tell me I didn't completely mess this up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Formulation of the LPP:**

Step 1: Declare the decision variables. You should decide how many $A$ and $B$ to produce. Let $x$ and $y$ be the numbers of the boxes, respectively.

Step 2: Make up the objective function. The profit (or revenue) function is $R=4.25x+6.55y$.

Step 3: Define the constrains. 
$$\begin{cases}6x+12y\le 5400 \ \ \text{(peanuts constraint)}\\
\ \ \ \ x+3y\le 1200 \ \ \text{(M&Ms constraint)}\\
\ \ 4x+2y\le 2400 \ \ \text{(raisins constraint)}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\ge 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(non-negativity constraint)}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ y\ge 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(non-negativity constraint)}\\
\end{cases}$$

**Solution of the LPP (graphical):**

Step 1: Draw the feasible region (the green area):

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]

Step 2: Find the corner points of the feasible region:
$$O(0,0); A(0,400); B(300,300); C(500,200); D(600,0).$$

Step 3: Evaluate the objective function at the corner points and choose the optimal value:

$$\begin{align}R(0,0)&=0;\\
R(0,400)&=2620;\\
R(300,300)&=3240;\\
R(500,200)&=3435 \ \text{(max)};\\
R(600,0)&=2550.\end{align}$$
See [WA solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%204.25x%2B6.55y%20subject%20to%206x%2B12y%3C%3D5400;%20x%2B3y%3C%3D1200;%204x%2B2y%3C%3D2400;%20x%3E%3D0;%20y%3E%3D0).

Answer (score 0):

To do it by hand, imagine you only make A boxes.  How many can you make?  What is the limiting component?  How much money do you make?  Now if you make fewer A boxes and free up some of the limiting component, allowing you to make B boxes, is that good?  For example, if peanuts were limiting you would have to skip two boxes of A to make a box of B.  That is a bad deal because you trade two 4.25s for one 6.55.  If the trade is profitable, keep doing it until you run out of something.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to maximize or minimize? Ostensibly, the profit. This would be 
$$
4.25A + 6.55B
$$

So yes, there are two variables here.

How many boxes can you make?

Well, that depends on your supplies. So the three food items will create three **constraints**. For example, If each A box uses 6 oz. peanuts and each B box uses 12 oz. peanuts, then $6A + 12B$ better be less than or equal to 5400, unless you can magically create some peanuts!

And yes, I get the same breakup that you do, but $500A + 200B \neq 3685$.